# How to output checkbox selections into a frame with python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

I am trying to create a simple payment calculator that takes input from multiple checkboxes and uses that to calculate a total cost. I want the user to be able to select the different services they want and then the function would take that and calculate the total cost based on which services they have selected. How do I get my Total Cost function to output into the bottom right frame to the right of "billing total"?
Here is what I have so far:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

import random
import datetime

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1100x950+0+0")
root.title("NLG Order Processing")
root.configure(background = 'light blue')

total_cost = 0

def Exit():
    root.destroy()
    return

def OrderNum():
    order1=random.randint(1000, 10000)
    order2=('FW'+str(order1))
    ordnum.set(order2)

def TotalCost():
    total_cost = 0
    if cmdCustomFitting.get() == "None":
        total_cost = total_cost + 0
    elif cmdCustomFitting.get() == "Iron Fitting-$125":
        total_cost = total_cost + 125
    elif cmdCustomFitting.get() == "Wood and Hybrid Fitting-$125":
        total_cost = total_cost + 125
    elif cmdCustomFitting.get() == "Full Set Fitting-$225":
        total_cost = total_cost + 225
    elif cmdCustomFitting.get() == "Putter Analysis-$75":
        total_cost = total_cost + 75
    else:
        total_cost = total_cost + 0
    
    
    if cmdClubRepair.get() == "None":
        total_cost = total_cost + 0
    elif cmdClubRepair.get() == "Grip installation-$4/each":
        total_cost = total_cost + 4
    elif cmdClubRepair.get() == "Save Grip-$6/each":
        total_cost = total_cost + 6
    elif cmdClubRepair.get() == "Lengthen Shaft-$8/each":
        total_cost = total_cost + 8
    elif cmdClubRepair.get() == "Loft Adjustments-$5/each":
        total_cost = total_cost + 5
    elif cmdClubRepair.get() == "Lie Adjustments-$5/each":
        total_cost = total_cost + 5
    elif cmdClubRepair.get() == "Re-Shaft/Shaft Installation-$15/each":
        total_cost = total_cost + 15
    elif cmdClubRepair.get() == "Save Adapter-$8/each":
        total_cost = total_cost + 8
    else:
        total_cost = total_cost + 0
    

    if cmdPrivateLesson.get() == "None":
        total_cost = total_cost + 0
    elif cmdPrivateLesson.get() == "Basic Birdie: One-Hour Lesson-$75":
        total_cost = total_cost + 75
    elif cmdPrivateLesson.get() == "Eager Eagle: (4) One-Hour Lessons-$275":
        total_cost = total_cost + 275
    elif cmdPrivateLesson.get() == "Double Eagle: (8) One-Hour Lessons-$500":
        total_cost = total_cost + 500
    else:
        total_cost = total_cost + 0

    
    if cmdSimulation.get() == "None":
        total_cost = total_cost + 0
    elif cmdSimulation.get() == "30 Minute Range-$10":
        total_cost = total_cost + 10
    elif cmdSimulation.get() == "30 Minute Range-$10":
        total_cost = total_cost + 10
    elif cmdSimulation.get() == "9 Hole Sim-Golf-$20/person":
        total_cost = total_cost + 20
    elif cmdSimulation.get() == "18 Hole Sim-Golf-$30/person":
        total_cost = total_cost + 30
    else:
        total_cost = total_cost + 0
    
    

EmpUsername=StringVar()
EmpPassword=StringVar()
CustID=StringVar()
F_name=StringVar()
L_name=StringVar()
Email=StringVar()
Cust_phone_num=StringVar()
discountcode=StringVar()
discountamount=StringVar
Usercardname=StringVar()
Usercardnum=StringVar()
Cardexpdate=StringVar()
Usersocialsec=StringVar()
ordnum=StringVar()
Service_num=StringVar()
Billing_total=StringVar()
Totalcost=StringVar("")


Tops=Frame(root, width=1350, height=50, bd=16, relief = "flat")
Tops.pack(side=TOP)
LF=Frame(root, width=700, height=650, bd=16, relief="flat")
LF.pack(side=LEFT)
RF=Frame(root, width=600, height=650, bd=16, relief="flat")
RF.pack(side=RIGHT)

Tops.configure(background="light blue")
LF.configure(background="light blue")
RF.configure(background= "light blue")

LeftInsideLF=Frame(LF, width=700, height=100, bd=8, relief= "raise")
LeftInsideLF.pack(side=TOP)
LeftInsideLFLF=Frame(LF, width=700, height=500, bd=8, relief="raise")
LeftInsideLFLF.pack(side=LEFT)

RightInsideLF=Frame(RF, width=700, height=500, bd=8, relief = "raise")
RightInsideLF.pack(side=TOP)
#RightInsideLFLF=Frame(RF, width=700, height=500, bd=8, relief = "raise")
#RightInsideLFLF.pack(side=RIGHT)
RightInsideLFF=Frame(RF, width=300, height=300, bd=8, relief = "raise")
RightInsideLFF.pack(side=TOP)

lblInfo = Label (Tops, font=("times", 50, 'bold'), text="    Next Level Golf Order Processing    ", bd=10, anchor="w")
lblInfo.grid(row=0, column=0)

#Log In Page 
TextUsername=Entry(LeftInsideLF, font=('times', 12), width = 11, textvariable="Username").grid(row=0, column=1)
lblUsername=Label(LeftInsideLF, font=('times', 12), width=11, text="Username:", bd=10, anchor="w").grid(row=0, column=0)
TextPassword=Entry(LeftInsideLF,font=('times', 12), width=11, textvariable='Password').grid(row=1, column=1)
lblPassword=Label(LeftInsideLF, font=('times', 12), width=11, text="Password:", bd=10, anchor="w").grid(row=1, column=0)

#Log in Button
btnlogin = Button(LeftInsideLF, pady=8, bd=8, fg="black",font=('times', 12), width=11, text="Login").grid(row=2, column=0)

#Returning
cmdReturningCustomer=Checkbutton(LeftInsideLFLF, font=('times', 12), text='Returning Customer (ID only)' , width=30)
cmdReturningCustomer.grid(row=0, column =0)

#Customer ID
lblCustomerID=Label(LeftInsideLFLF, font=('times', 12), width=11, text="Customer ID:", bd=10)
lblCustomerID.grid(row=3, column=0)
TextCustomerID=Entry(LeftInsideLFLF, font=('times', 12), textvariable='CustID')
TextCustomerID.grid(row=3, column=1)

#New Customer First Name
TextNewCustFName=Entry(LeftInsideLFLF, font=('times', 12), textvariable='F_name')
TextNewCustFName.grid(row=4, column=1)
lblNewCustFName=Label(LeftInsideLFLF, font=('times', 12), width=11, text="First Name:", bd=10)
lblNewCustFName.grid(row=4, column=0)
#New Customer Last Name
TextNewCustLName=Entry(LeftInsideLFLF, font=('times', 12), textvariable='L_name')
TextNewCustLName.grid(row=5, column=1)
lblNewCustLName=Label(LeftInsideLFLF, font=('times', 12), width=11, text="Last Name:", bd=10)
lblNewCustLName.grid(row=5, column=0)
#New Customer EMail
TextNewCustEMail=Entry(LeftInsideLFLF, font=('times', 12), textvariable='Email:')
TextNewCustEMail.grid(row=6, column=1)
lblNewCustEMail=Label(LeftInsideLFLF, font=('times', 12), width=11, text="Email:", bd=10)
lblNewCustEMail.grid(row=6, column=0)
#New Customer Phone 
TextNewCustPhone=Entry(LeftInsideLFLF, font=('times', 12), textvariable='User_phone_num')
TextNewCustPhone.grid(row=7, column=1)
lblNewCustPhone=Label(LeftInsideLFLF, font=('times', 12), width=11, text="Phone Number:", bd=10)
lblNewCustPhone.grid(row=7, column=0)

#Services entry
lblServiceSelect=Label(RightInsideLF,font=('times', 14, 'bold'),text="Service Selection",fg='black',bd=10,anchor='w')
lblServiceSelect.grid(row=0, column=0)
#Custom Fitting
lblCustomFitting=Label(RightInsideLF, font=('times',12,),text="Custom Fitting", fg='black',bd=10,anchor='w')
lblCustomFitting.grid(row=1, column=0)
cmdCustomFitting=ttk.Combobox(RightInsideLF,font=('times',12))
cmdCustomFitting['value']=('None','Iron Fitting-$125','Wood and Hybrid Fitting-$125','Full Set Fitting-$225','Putter Analysis-$75')
cmdCustomFitting.grid(row=1, column=1)
#Club Repair
lblClubRepair=Label(RightInsideLF, font=('times',12,),text="Club Repair", fg='black',bd=10,anchor='w')
lblClubRepair.grid(row=2, column=0)
cmdClubRepair=ttk.Combobox(RightInsideLF,font=('times',12))
cmdClubRepair['value']=('None','Grip installation-$4/each','Save Grip-$6/each','Lengthen Shaft-$8/each','Loft Adjustments-$5/each','Lie Adjustments-$5/each',
'Re-Shaft/Shaft Installation-$15/each','Save Adapter-$8/each')
cmdClubRepair.grid(row=2, column=1)
#Private Lesson
lblPrivateLesson=Label(RightInsideLF, font=('times',12,),text="Private Lesson", fg='black',bd=10,anchor='w')
lblPrivateLesson.grid(row=3, column=0)
cmdPrivateLesson=ttk.Combobox(RightInsideLF,font=('times',12))
cmdPrivateLesson['value']=('None','Basic Birdie: One-Hour Lesson-$75','Eager Eagle: (4) One-Hour Lessons-$275','Double Eagle: (8) One-Hour Lessons-$500')
cmdPrivateLesson.grid(row=3, column=1)
#Simulation
lblSimulation=Label(RightInsideLF, font=('times',12,),text="Simulation", fg='black',bd=10,anchor='w')
lblSimulation.grid(row=4, column=0)
cmdSimulation=ttk.Combobox(RightInsideLF,font=('times',12))
cmdSimulation['value']=('None','30 Minute Range-$10','60 Minute Range-$17','9 Hole Sim-Golf-$20/person','18 Hole Sim-Golf-$30/person')
cmdSimulation.grid(row=4, column=1)
#Discount Code
TextDiscountCode=Entry(RightInsideLF, font=('times', 12), textvariable='discountcode')
TextDiscountCode.grid(row=5, column=1)
lblDiscountCode=Label(RightInsideLF, font=('times', 12), text="Enter discount code (if applicable):",fg='black', bd=10, anchor='w')
lblDiscountCode.grid(row=5, column=0)


#Confirmation Page
lblConfPage=Label(RightInsideLFF, font=('times', 14,'bold'), text='Confirmation Page',fg='black', bd=10)
lblConfPage.grid(row=0, column=0)
#Customer ID
lblCustomerID=Label(RightInsideLFF, font=('times', 12), width=11, text="Customer ID:", bd=10)
lblCustomerID.grid(row=1, column=0)
lblordnum=Label(RightInsideLFF, font=('times', 12), width=11, text="Order Number:", bd=10)
lblordnum.grid(row=2, column=0)
lblServiceord=Label(RightInsideLFF, font=('times', 12), width=11, text="Services Ordered:", bd=10)
lblServiceord.grid(row=3, column=0)
lblbilltotal=Label(RightInsideLFF, font=('times', 12), width=11, text="Billing Total:", bd=10)
lblbilltotal.grid(row=4, column=0)


#Total cost button
btnTotalCost = Button(RightInsideLF, pady=8, bd=8, fg="black",font=('times', 12), width=16, text="Calculate Total Cost", command=TotalCost).grid(row=6, column=1)
# Total cost button should be on the Service Selection page (instead of the booking confirmation)

#Order Number button
#btnOrderNum = Button(RightInsideLFF, pady=8, bd=8, fg="black",font=('times', 12), width=11, text="Order Number", command=OrderNum).grid(row=5, column=1)
# Jones doesn't want this button on this frame. 

#Exit Button
btnSubmit = Button(RightInsideLFF, pady=8, bd=8, fg="black",font=('times', 12), width=11, text="Submit", command=Exit).grid(row=5, column=2)



root.mainloop()'''
```

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code in your question. A proper [mcve] for this question only needs a couple of checkbuttons and a label, plus enough extra code to illustrate the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You need a label

```
Label(whatever, textvariable=Totalcost)
```

and after you calculate the cost

```
Totalcost.set(total_cost)
```